# Why is my SESSION_ID invalid immediately after authenticating my JWT token?

Tags: python, jwt, simple-salesforce, session-id

So I am trying to get `simplesalesforce` working in a dev account for proof of concept (and, so far, I've been making a proper mess of it).

I have FINALLY managed to successfully connect using a JWT token. However, the instant (and I do mean "instant"---this seems to happen immediately) I try to do anything with my `simple_salesforce.api.Salesforce object`, I get
`[{'message': 'Session expired or invalid', 'errorCode': 'INVALID_SESSION_ID'}]`.

`simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceExpiredSession: Expired session for https://MY_ORG-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/query/...`

Now, this seems to be (or "was") a common issue for people using Postman, where the solution seems to be to enable `Follow Authorization header`. I am not sure how to implement such a thing in my Python code (nor does it seem like something `simplesalesforce` would fail to account for.

I have checked all the settings I can think of (and have been indicated in other threads here and elsewhere), but to no avail.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: This is the only place that looks problematic to me, but I think just that the auth time is less than 1 hour.]

[image]

[image]

I'm happy to add more, but I'm trying to avoid making this post/question just impossible to read.

Here is my code (note, I am using the `instance_url` for my request, not the auth).

```
import jwt
import requests
import datetime
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from simple_salesforce.exceptions import SalesforceAuthenticationFailed
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from pprint import pprint

load_dotenv()

client_id = consumer_key = os.getenv('consumer_key')
client_secret = consumer_secret = os.getenv('consumer_secret')
username=os.getenv('sf_username')
private_key=os.getenv('private_key')

def jwt_login(consumer_id, username, private_key):
    endpoint = 'https://login.salesforce.com'
    jwt_payload = jwt.encode(
        {
            'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=30),
            'iss': consumer_id,
            'aud': endpoint,
            'sub': username
        },
        private_key,
        algorithm='RS256',
    )

    result = requests.post(
        endpoint + '/services/oauth2/token',
        data={
            'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
            'assertion': jwt_payload
        },
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    )
    body = result.json()
    pprint(body)
    if result.status_code != 200:
        raise SalesforceAuthenticationFailed(body['error'], body['error_description'])
    sf = Salesforce(instance_url=body['instance_url'], session_id=body['access_token'])
    return sf

sf = jwt_login(consumer_id=client_id,username=username,private_key=private_key)

query = sf.query("SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact")
```

I am just at a complete loss and unsure how to get more information about what is wrong to figure it out.

Comment: Try unchecking the beta JWT access token option.

Comment: @identigral Dude, you're a freaking GOD. I can't believe how long I spent trying to figure that out.

Should I delete my question? If you answer it, I'll accept the answer.